# mapbox gl codepoint error

Tags: angularjs, geolocation, mapbox-gl-js

I am using *mapbox-gl.js* in my Angular app. When I turn on HTML5 geolocation API and zoom in to my current location, sometimes I am getting an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'codePoint' of undefined

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an error I've seen before. Can you [open an issue on the `mapbox-gl-js` repository](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/new) with a demo?